# Pallet session: QueuedKeys vs NextKeys

Tags: pallet, storage, session

I need to interact with `pallet_session`, in particular to read validator set for the next session. As far as I understand, this data is stored in two places:

- `QueuedKeys`, which is just `Vec<(T::ValidatorId, T::Keys)>`
- `NextKeys`, which is a mapping from `T::ValidatorId` to `T::Keys`

After scrolling pallet code, it seems to me that these two containers are kinda equivalent and it is not clear for me why there is a need for both of them. Hence, I do not know whether I'm guaranteed that they always contain the same data and I can use any of them or I'm missing something.

So the question is: is there any difference between `QueuedKeys` and `NextKeys`, of course apart from the lookup/access interface (vector vs map).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point that you are missing is that `NextKeys` can only be set via the `set_keys` transaction.

Once a new session is being enacted, if the validator set has changed, `QueuedKeys` is formed from the list of new authorities (coming from `SessionManager`), amalgamated with keys that have already been provided by potential validators via `set_keys`.

Comment: if i need to add pallet_session in a running chain how can i set authorities from AURA to session ?